# The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE)) and Compiler Error Message: CS1583

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am debugging the web application on browser as application built in .Net framework with Knockout.js, MVC 4.5.

Below two issues are occurring in order on my machine as First:

- The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))
  [Screen Shot for handle error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg5F9.jpg)

and on refreshing browser again and again for multiple time, below second error is shown as:

- Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1583: 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\319fdbfa\d4467656\CSC7451AF8AE7204B6CA14A4B158BEA80FA.TMP' is not a valid Win32 resource file

For it [Screen shot of Compilation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK3Lu.jpg)

And again on multiple time refreshing site, first issue is shown on screen and after that second.

### Note

I have tried all the solutions as shared in other posts as:

1. taskkill  /fi "imagename eq webdev.webserver40.exe"
2. server where website sits, open the command prompt and run the command with framework path: aspnet_regiis.exe -i -
3. Include 'Min Pool Size =1'  in the connection string.
4. Clear out the temporary ASP.Net files on the server
5. Clear out the bin folder files

However same application is debugging successfully without any error on my colleagues machine with same environment and configuration.

Comment: This problem is not knockout.js-related. It looks like you have a problem with an unmanaged resource in your project, perhaps a third-party library which isn't installed as your solution expects.

Comment: How can I identify that which libraries not installed?

Comment: Sometime application is running and sometime giving error.

Comment: Perhaps you could step through the code, line by line, until the exception occurs. There is a large number of things which could be causing this, so if it's sometimes happening and sometimes not then you can reduce the number of possibilities by determining the circumstances under which this problem arises. I can't be any more specific than that due to the wide possibilities.

Comment: Same code is running successfully on my colleagues machine with same machine configuration, however not on my system.

Comment: If you look carefully at the exception message you can see that it mentions "resource" - this _could_ be a language resource file or any embedded flat file which your colleague has but you haven't. Whatever it is, yours and your colleague's PCs don't have identical files and directory structure, or the same rights to the entire file and directory structure. Something about your workspace is different.

Comment: I have compared all of the things, but all are identical, So can you suggest any other way to resolve it.